# Laravel: searching relationships with conditions and retrieving the records

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have some related tables in a school DB. I have Student, StdAct, and Transactions. Student has an account for each year. So a student may have many accounts (based on the year and grade). For example: Student (id:2) may have the following accounts

- StdAct (id:10, student_id:2, year: 2018, grade: 10th)
- StdAct (id:23, student_id:2, year: 2019, grade: 11th)
- StdAct (id:53, student_id:2, year: 2020, grade: 12th).. And so on.

A StdAct may have many Transactions. For example, StdAct (id:10, year: 2018, grade: 10th) may have the following transactions:

- Tran (id:110, act_id:10, Amount: 20$, Created_at: 2020-10-10)
- Tran (id:340, act_id:10, Amount: 40$, Created_at: 2020-11-10).. And so on.

I would like to print a report like this:

Item Std_name  Tran(Amount) Date

- 1    John        20$          2020-10-10
- 2    John        40$          2020-11-10
- 3    Dennis      44$          2020-11-02

And so on..

Given (year and grade), I would like to do search and find all StdActs with related transactions and related students' names based on given input from user (year and grade).

I also may need to generate the same report based on given two dates (user's input). So I would search transactions between two given dates and find related StdActs and Students (we need std_name).

Here are my models

```php
class StdActs extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'StdActs';

    public function student()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Students', 'student_id');
        //return $this->belongsTo('App\Students', 'id');
    }


    public function transactions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Transactions','act_id');
    }

}

class Students extends Model
{
    protected $table ='Students';

    public function StdActs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\StdActs', 'student_id', 'id');
    }
}

class Transactions extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Transactions';

    public function StdAct()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\StdActs');
    }
}
```

Note:
I tried some similar cases (but not the case that I am asking about above) like the following:

```php
$stdActs = StdActs::whereHas('student', function($query){
    $query->where ('std_name', 'like' , '%' . request ( 'keywords'   ) . '%');
    })
    ->where('year_id'  , '=', request ( 'year'   ) )
    ->where('school_id', '=', request ( 'school' ) )
    ->get();
```

However, it only returns StdActs.. There is no student_name..
If it is possible to get std_names here; then I think we can solve the original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original query is restricted with `whereHas()` to instances of `StdActs` that meet the requirements, but you don't ask to [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the relationship. This is done using the `with()` method, and then we [constrain that](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) with the same requirements as before.

```php
$key     = '%' . request('keywords') . '%';
$year    = request('year');
$school  = request('school');

$stdActs = StdActs::where('year_id', $year)
    ->where('school_id', $school)
    ->whereHas('student', fn ($q) => $q->where('std_name', 'like' , $key))
    ->with(['student' => fn ($q) => $q->where('std_name', 'like' , $key)])
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you so much @miken32!. It works fine. I added some code to select some columns from 'student' table. Here is what I have:
->with(
                [  
                    'student' => function($query) {
                        $query
                        ->where('std_name', 'like' , '%' . request('keywords') . '%')   ;
                    }
                ]
            )->with(  'student:id,std_name')